# Regular Expression to select every digit after a particular word

Tags: regex

My problem is that i'm trying to find all number after HJK/ text and replace them by 'X'. (I'm using javascript)

INPUT:

```
ABC1234_DE5_FG_678 HJK/1/1/1/1.1
ABC1234_DE5_FG_789 HJK/1/2/1/3/5/2.1
ABC1234_DE5_FG_8910 HJK/ 0/2/1/3/5/1.1
```

OUTPUT:

```
ABC1234_DE5_FG_678 HJK/X/X/X/X.X
ABC1234_DE5_FG_789 HJK/X/X/X/X/X/X.X
ABC1234_DE5_FG_8910 HJK/ X/X/X/X/X/X.X
```

Can someone help me with creating a regular expression for above requirement? Thank you very much!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking questions.

Comment: I'm using javascript @Sweeper

Comment: I'm using javascript @niyasc

Comment: Hi @Aaron! I can do that with javascript code. But actually i'm checking for feasibility to do that with pure regex.

Comment: positive look behind can do that but this feature still experiment and not yet supported, you could split the `string` and then replace every digit.

Comment: You can run ```^(?:HJK\/)*\d+``` and then another command to replace the number after the decimal.

Comment: Thanks all for your helpful comments! I think solution below by Oliver Hao is what i'm looking for. Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(?<=HJK.*)(\d)
```

[This is demo](https://regex101.com/r/kdmUnV/1)

This is code by javascript:

```js
const regex = /(?<=HJK.*)(\d)/gm;
const str = `ABC1234_DE5_FG_678 HJK/1/1/1/1.1
ABC1234_DE5_FG_789 HJK/1/2/1/3/5/2.1
ABC1234_DE5_FG_8910 HJK/0/2/1/3/5/1.1`;
const subst = `X`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Careful, it doesn't work in many JS engines (I thought it didn't work in any, but I just checked with Chrome and was surprised to see it now did). You can check the lookbehind line in the [MDN's compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the warning @Aaron! Btw my code is running in node10 so would be good. Cheers!